# "Fragment file is not indexed" in Signac/R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am currently running an snATAC-seq analysis and performed the following command:

```
chrom_assay <- CreateChromatinAssay(
   counts = counts,
   sep = c(":", "-"),
   genome = 'mm10', 
   fragments = '../vignette_data/atac_v1_pbmc_10k_fragments.tsv', 
   min.cells = 10,
   min.features = 200
)
```

Now, my error comes out as

```
Error in CreateFragmentObject(path = fragments, cells = cells,
validate.fragments = validate.fragments, 
:Fragment file is not indexed.
```

Could someone provide possible solutions to mitigate this?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the advise from the Signac developer in [https://github.com/timoast/signac/issues/7#issuecomment-513934624](https://github.com/timoast/signac/issues/7) , the folder with the fragments file should also contain the fragment index file (.tbi). For example, for the human 10X PBMC vignette data (https://satijalab.org/signac/articles/pbmc_vignette.html): atac_v1_pbmc_10k/atac_v1_pbmc_10k_fragments.tsv.gz and
atac_v1_pbmc_10k/atac_v1_pbmc_10k_fragments.tsv.gz.tbi should be in the same folder. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [Github issue](https://github.com/stuart-lab/signac/issues/242#issuecomment-693666737) to regenerate .tbi file

Briefly, run the following cmds in linux/unix terminal :

1. gzip -d <fragment.tsv.gz>
2. bgzip <fragment.tsv>
3. tabix -p bed <fragment.tsv.gz>

Comment: Hi Wei. Please could you edit this answer so that it's more self contained? Links are helpful, but when an answer depends on external content it introduces avoidable complication/dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the documentation of the function `CreateChromatinAssay`, the `fragments =`  file should be a tabix file (ending in .tbi) containing the index with fragments of your data, or a `Fragments` object in R.

Apparently, first you will need to create the `Fragments` object in R from your tsv data, using the function `CreateFragmentObject()`. Take a look at: https://satijalab.org/signac/reference/fragments .